# Check update query result in CI + SQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

This is my simple code in CI's `model` named `schedule_m` :

```
$query = $this->db->update('CUST_GATH', 
      array(
           'new_email' => $data['new_email'],
            'new_hp' => $data['new_hp']
      ), 
      array(
          'name'=>$data['name'], 
          'hp'=>$data['hp'], 
          'email'=>$data['email']
      )
 );
return $query;
```

In `MySQL`, i can check the result of my update query simply by doing :

```
$result = $this->schedule_m->update('schedule', $data);

if($result == true)
```

But this is not working in SQL Server. The `$result` is always true.

What should i do?

Thanks  a lot for your help

**UPDATE**

I tried to use `affected_rows`:

```
    $this->db->update('CUST_GATH', array('send_to' => $data['send_to'],
        'is_email' => 1), array('name'=>$data['name'], 'hp'=>$data['hp'], 'email'=>$data['email']));
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

But now my webservice stop working : `Response does not contain any data.`

What is wrong here?

**Workaround**

I haven't solved this problem so my trick is to do SELECT **after** i UPDATE the specific data to check wether the data is updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `affected_rows` method with `JSON` output:

```
if($this->db->affected_rows())
{
   return $this->output
                        ->set_content_type('application/json')
                        ->set_output(json_encode(array('OK')));
}
```

or

```
if($this->db->affected_rows())
{
   return $this->output
                        ->set_content_type('application/json')
                        ->set_output(json_encode('OK'));
}
```

Comment: `Response does not contain any data.` mean you should return a data like: `if($this->db->affected_rows()){ return "OK";}`

Comment: @BlazeTama You have to say us what expecting your web service?

Comment: In your example, i expect it to return "OK" in JSON format

Answer (score 1):

You have to use number of affected row

```
$result = $this->schedule_m->update('schedule', $data);
if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
{
  return TRUE;
}else{
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: And should i use `affected_rows` in the `controller`?

Comment: Where you write your update query its in controller or model??